# How to make emulator have local settings?

Tags: ios, react-native, emulation

I'm using `Date` objects in my React Native app, and read that some of the settings in these objects might vary from country to country. I'm getting slightly different behaviour on my . real device compared to my iOS emulator, and want to make sure my emulator is set to the same country as my real device. Does anyone know how to control which country your emulator is set to?

Comment: I think this might help [How to change time and timezone in iPhone simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699671/how-to-change-time-and-timezone-in-iphone-simulator)

Comment: Perfecto, do you want to post a reply so I can accept it?

Comment: sure, i will reply