# Change system date on XCode Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to figure out how to specify a certain date on an XCode simulator, just like how you can simulate a location.  I need to specify a date to test a sunrise/sunset calculation, which varies by date.

I see you can set a time zone environment variable in the build scheme [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699671/how-to-change-time-and-timezone-in-iphone-simulator#:%7E:text=You%20can%20set%20the%20TZ%20environment%20variable%20in%20an%20Xcode%20Scheme%20to%20set%20the%20time%20zone%20just%20for%20that%20app.).

Is it possible to set a specific date that way?  If not, is there another way to set the date?

Comment: The simulator date is the same as your computer's date.if you want to test a function that needs a date, better to simply inject the appropriate `Date` to that function during your test

Comment: Yes, this makes the most sense - I can just set the `Date` argument in the function directly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Numerous ways to create a Date object...

Here's one method using `DateComponents` -- which may work well for your testing:

```
    var dc = DateComponents()

    dc.year = 2022
    dc.month = 8
    dc.day = 25
    dc.hour = 12
    dc.minute = 34
    dc.second = 55

    let testDate = Calendar.current.date(from: dc)
```